# AngularJs Promises within Promise

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

Hey guys I'm posting some data to a server then based on a couple of variables posting again to a different url inside the loop.

So far I'm using as an example:

```
    $scope.items = [{'name':'Test1','hasd':1,'hase':1},{'name':'Test2','hasd':0,'hase':1}];
    var promises = [];

    angular.forEach($scope.items,function(obj) {
    promises.push($http({
        type:'post',
        url:'test',
        data:obj
      }).then(function(response) { 
          if(response.status==201) {
             //do another http call
             if(obj.hasd==1) {
                $http({}).then(function() { 
                    var something=1; 
                });
             }
          }
        }));

   $q.all(promises).then(function(){
      alert('done');
   });
```

The problem I am having is that it's only looking at the initial $http call's promise rather then any internal calls. Is there a way to have all the $http calls be added to the promise inside the loop?

Cheers,
Ben

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
$http({}).then(function() { 
  var something=1; 
});
```

To:

```
return $http({}).then(function() { 
  var something=1; 
});
```

That means that your "outer" promise that you add to the `promises` array won't be resolved until the "inner" promise has completed.

The reason for this is that a `then` handler can return a value or another promise. To understand this, you need to understand that all `then` handlers creates a new promise. So there will always be one dangling promise at the end that no one cares about.

If your `then` handler doesn't return anything, then Javascript will (sort of) return `undefined` for you. So the promise created by your `then` handler will be resolved immediately with the value you returned, or `undefined` if you didn't return anything. But you can also return a new promise which is what gets passed back into your `promises` array.